# How to compare phone numbers between two Table and when phone numbers matched then update Column IsState with True otherwise false?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have Table A and Table B, both tables have column Phone numbers and if phone number matched between Table A and Table B then I would like to update column IsState to true and if not matched then False.

Comment: In which table is your isstate column present

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Update b
 Set b.isstate=Case when a.phone=b.phone then "true"
   Else "false" end
 From tableB b
 Full join tableA a
 On a.phone=b.phone
```

I am assuming the isstate column is in tableB here.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `IsState` is on `TableA`. You could use `LEFT JOIN` like this

```
UPDATE a
SET a.IsState = IIF(b.Id IS null, 0, 1)
From TableA a
LEFT JOIN TableB b ON a.PhoneNumber = b.PhoneNumber
```

Answer (score 0):

Cinsidering isstate is in TableA. Using join update, you can update the column. Following is the code:

```
Update TableA
     Set sstate=Case when TableA.phone=TableB.phone then "true"
       Else "false" end
     From TableA left join TableB 
     On TableA.phone=TableB.phone
```